# When adding certain floats in JavaScript the output of those particular floats returns long numbers

Tags: javascript, floating-point

```
I was trying to add a few decimal points initialized as variables and the output of the number was extremely long: 

var a = .1 ;
var b = .2 ;
var c = a + b ;
document.write(c) ;
```

The c variable returns a number of 0.30000000000000004, Ive searched high and wide and can't find an explanation why some floats return perfectly rounded answers and some dont.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: hey, it's pretty close ain't it?

Comment: Yea it is super close but Im reading the article that andybeli posted to try to get a better understanding of why some floats are drawn out more than others. Maybe if I create another variable and multiply .2 and .1 by 10 and divide it by 1 that might work.